# Making a position indicator 'map' of position in a scrollview iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, position

I have a view containing a scrollview the size of a large image, and i'd like to add a position indicator for where you are in the scrollview, like a map in games.

I've created a smaller view on top of the scrollview with a smaller version of the image, and I'm wondering how I could add a rectangle relative to the size and position of the zoom scale of the scrollview in my smaller view, to indicate on the small image what part of the larger image you're currently looking at? I'm targeting iOS 5+ using ARC.

here's what i have so far - it seems to set the origin correctly, but when i zoom it gets smaller when it should get bigger and vice versa:

```
int scrollxint = self.scrollView.bounds.origin.x;
int scrollyint = self.scrollView.bounds.origin.y;
int scrollxlength = self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
int scrollylength = self.scrollView.contentSize.height;

int reducedscrollxint = (scrollxint*0.05);
int reducedscrollyint = (scrollyint*0.05);
int reducedscrollxlength = (scrollxlength*0.05);
int reducedscrollylength = (scrollylength*0.05);

areaFrame.frame = CGRectMake(reducedscrollxint, reducedscrollyint, reducedscrollxlength, reducedscrollylength);
[self.mapView addSubview:areaFrame];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the zoom scale relative to the original size of the area indicator to make this work, but this code is working for me:

```
int scrollxint = self.scrollView.bounds.origin.x;
int scrollyint = self.scrollView.bounds.origin.y;

float scale = self.scrollView.zoomScale;

int reducedscrollxint = (scrollxint*0.05);
int reducedscrollyint = (scrollyint*0.05);


areaFrame.frame = CGRectMake(reducedscrollxint, reducedscrollyint, (10/scale), (6.5/scale));
[self.mapView addSubview:areaFrame];
```